# password+salt php to java

Tags: java, php, password-encryption

I'm trying to get this code in PHP to Java but I am getting different results , where is the error ?

PHP Code

```
public function hashSSHA($password) {

        $salt = sha1(rand());
        $salt = substr($salt, 0, 10);
        $salt = "172ba59e6b";
        $encrypted = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);
        $hash = array("salt" => $salt, "encrypted" => $encrypted);
        return $hash;
    }
```

Java

```
private Map senha(String password){
    Map<String, String> pass = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String salt = sha1(Integer.toString((int) Math.random()));
    salt = salt.substring(0,10).toLowerCase();
    salt = "172ba59e6b";
    String tobase64 = toSHA1((password + salt).getBytes()) + salt;
    byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(tobase64.getBytes());
    String encrypted = new String(encodedBytes);
    String[] array;
    pass.put("salt",salt);
    pass.put("encrypted",encrypted);
    Log.d("asd",encrypted);

    return pass;

}
```

Java sha1 function

```
public String sha1(String s) {
        try {
            // Create MD5 Hash
            MessageDigest digest = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            digest.update(s.getBytes());
            byte messageDigest[] = digest.digest();

            // Create Hex String
            StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
            for (int i = 0; i < messageDigest.length; i++)
                hexString.append(String.format("%02X", 0xFF & messageDigest[i]));
            return hexString.toString();

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Java sha1bin

```
public static String toSHA1(byte[] convertme) {
        MessageDigest md = null;
        try {
            md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        }
        catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new String(md.digest(convertme));
    }
```

Where am I going wrong ? Is there any simple way to do ?

On java with salt=172ba59e6b:

```
String tobase64 = toSHA1(("muranga21" + salt).getBytes()) + salt;
```

Return: ���{��b�v����r���t�172ba59e6b

On PHP with salt=172ba59e6b:

```
$sha1 = sha1("muranga21" . $salt, true) . $salt;
```

Return: ���{��b�v����r���t�172ba59e6b

But when i try do base64 encode:

On php i got:

o/exe6eNHGKbdvy6jd1ym6uddKExNzJiYTU5ZTZi

On java:

77+977+9e++/ve+/vRxi77+9du+/ve+/vXLvv73vv73vv71077+9MTcyYmE1OWU2Yg==

Comment: **Security Vulnerability:** *Never* use a `String` type to hold passwords (e.g. your `senha` and `sha1` methods). Use `byte` arrays (i.e. `byte[]`) instead and make sure to overwrite their contents *before* throwing away the reference.

Comment: Do not create your own password hashing function. Use PHP's Password Hashing API! http://php.net/password

Answer (score 0):

You're using a random salt. Of course you will get different results everytime you run the code...

Comment: I'm talking about encrypted with same salt got differents return:
I have added this line: $salt = "172ba59e6b" on PHP and salt="172ba59e6b" on Java.

Comment: On java with salt 172ba59e6b:
String tobase64 = toSHA1(("muranga21" + salt).getBytes()) + salt; 
Return: ���{��b�v����r���t�172ba59e6b
On PHP with salt 172ba59e6b:
$sha1 = sha1("muranga21" . $salt, true) . $salt;
Return: ���{��b�v����r���t�172ba59e6b

But when i try do base64 encode:
On php i got:
o/exe6eNHGKbdvy6jd1ym6uddKExNzJiYTU5ZTZi

On java:
77+977+9e++/ve+/vRxi77+9du+/ve+/vXLvv73vv73vv71077+9MTcyYmE1OWU2Yg==